# Rectangle is supposed to move on the screen but disappears instead

Tags: c#, .net, drawing

So I am trying to do a mini "tower defense" game.
Now, my current problem is that I can't get my picturebox to "shoot" a rectangle "bullet"

I declare these variables at the start

```
    Rectangle Bullet = new Rectangle(225, 400, 10, 25); //position of this shouldn't matter since it's not drawed instantly and it's later moved moved under the picturebox.
    private bool bulletIsActive = false;
    private int update_speed = 250;
```

Also, the timer is declared **AFTER** InitializeComponent();

```
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = update_speed;
        timer1.Start();
```

I have Eventhandler for key presses, and there I have (Only included Keys.Space since the others are irrelevant.

```
private void Paaikkuna_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            case Keys.Space:
                if(bulletIsActive == false)
                {
                    bulletIsActive = true; //set bool bullet to true and draw the bullet

                    Bullet.Location = new Point(playerX, playerY); //set bullet location at picturebox
                }
                break;
```

Then I have Paaikkuna_paint (form obviously)

```
private void Paaikkuna_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if(bulletIsActive == true) //if bulletIsActive == true (Which happens when I press space, draw bullet)
        {
             e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, Bullet); 
        }
```

That all works fine, when I press space and move the "tower" (picturebox) to either side, the rectangle will be there.
But here is the problem

My idea was to move the Bullet using timer_tick, the code looks like this. It's supposed to move the Bullet -10Y each timer tick, but instead of that, it just disappears.

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int bulletY = Bullet.Location.Y;
        int bulletX = Bullet.Location.X;

        if (bulletY>-10 && bulletIsActive == true) //checks if Bullet.Location.Y is >-10 (if not, it's not on screen and it can be "killed") and also if bullet == true
        {
            Bullet.Location = new Point(bulletX, bulletY - 10);
        }
        else
        {
            bulletIsActive = false;
        }

    }
```

TL;DR The rectangle just "disappears" even tho the coordinates tell that it should be moving upwards on the screen just above the picturebox.

I really don't know why this is happening and tried so many things already.

Full code here http://pastebin.com/WVpLzxUT (in case you want a better look at it)

Comment: You have a rectangle variable named Bullet, and a boolean variable named bullet.  Please pick better names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Bullet` is a `Rectangle` and you want it to be painted at new coordinates on each `Tick` you need to `Invalidate` the `Control` it is supposed to be painted on:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int bulletY = Bullet.Location.Y;
    int bulletX = Bullet.Location.X;

    //checks if Bullet.Location.Y is >-10 
    //(if not, it's not on screen and it can be "killed") 
    //and also if bullet == true
    if (bulletY > -10 && bullet == true) 
    {
        Bullet.Location = new Point(bulletX, bulletY - 10);
        Paaikkuna.Invalidate();   // <-- trigger the paint event!
    }
    else
    {
        bullet = false;
    }

}
```

Btw: Instead of `if (bullet == true)` you should 1) name it nicer, say, bulletIsActive and 2) make use of the datatype `bool` it has:  `if (bulletIsActive)`

Comment: Oh. Well, you will need to learn quite a few things about Winforms graphics then.. Have fun, writing __small__ games is a nice intro.. Here the lesson is that `Rectangles` are nothing but four integers and don't get painted automatically..

Comment: Now that you said " Here the lesson is that Rectangles are nothing but four integers and don't get painted automatically", it makes sense now why it didn't work :)